# Does a round-the-world ticket get invalidated if you miss a flight in the midst of an itinerary?

Tags: tickets, around-the-world

In normal tickets, it would get all of your subsequent flights invalid once you miss a flight in the midst of the whole itinerary. How about the case on the RTW ticket?

Usually the RTW ticket doesn't allow you to change the route, but allows you to change the date of the flight. If you miss a flight, can you change the date of the (missed) flight after the departure date?

Or can I buy a separate ticket by myself to make up for the missed flight and resume the remaining part of the itinerary from the next city onward?

If the specific program is required, it is the Star Alliance award ticket redeemed on ANA mileage program. But I would like to get a generic answer, if possible.

Comment: @Giorgio It is not a duplicate at all. This question is about the missed flight while the linked is the denied entry.

Comment: The generic answer would be: You have to look in the ticket rules. Some tickets might allow changes after the scheduled flight date, others do not, some allow to skip segments, others do not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. They do. The exact rule vary by alliance but when the Star Alliance one which I used last year, stipulates that any missed flight voids the entire ticket. This really scared me as I nearly missed two flights, one with me making it to the airport 10 minutes ahead of flight (and making it!) and the other within 40 minutes. For the first I was late because two trams broke on the way and for the second, there were grieving workers blocking a major highway I was stuck on. Plan accordingly and give yourself extra time.

You can though reschedule up to three hours before for a fee, so if you know certainly that you will miss a flight, you can call them. My ticket was purchased in Canadian dollars, so the fee was $200 CAD, it might be different depending on your currency.